# I cannot get the Quillback innards

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

So I go to the Western approach and the funny guy with the funny mask in the funny stuff tells me that I need to get Quillback intestines or something. However, I'm having trouble finding Quillbacks. I walked around killing enemies for an hour and a half, but apparently none of them were Quillbacks. Am I able to find a Quillback anywhere else or is this just a one time thing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is one of the quests that can get pretty grindy, as quillbacks are not that common, *and* getting intestines is not automatic when you kill them in the designated quest area. So you really just have to keep hunting them until you find those precious guts.

On the other hand, quillbacks are pretty large and visible from a little ways away. Here is what they look like:

[image]